# Extending a PIL decoder

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a file which contains a single image of a specific format at a
specific offset. I can already get a file-like for the embedded image
which supports `read()`, `seek()`, and `tell()`. I want to take advantage
of an existing PIL decoder to handle the embedded image, but be able to
treat the entire file as an "image file" in its own right.

I have not been able to figure out how to do this given the
[documentation
available](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm) and was wondering if anyone had any insights as to how I could
do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did to solve this was to derive from the `ImageFile.ImageFile` child belonging to the embedded format instead of `ImageFile.ImageFile` directly. Then in `_open()` I replaced `self.fp` with the file-like to the embedded image, and called the parent's `_open()`. I can't say that I'm particularly happy doing it this way, but it seems to have worked.

Comment: Sounds like good code reuse. Q: Did your approach result in a new image type and extension being registered, and if so was there anything tricky about doing it?

Comment: @martineau: I needed this to operate on an existing binary stream so I didn't attempt to register anything. To be specific, I was reading a PNG embedded in a game datafile.

Answer (score 9):

The relevant chapter of the docs is [this one](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/decoder.htm) and I think it's fairly clear: if for example you want to decode image files in the new `.zap`-format, you write a `ZapImagePlugin.py` module which must perform a couple things:

- have a `class ZapImageFile(ImageFile.ImageFile):` with string attributes `format` and `format_description`, and a hook-method `def _open(self)` (of which more later);
- at module level, `Image.register_open('zap', ZapImageFile)` and `Image.register_extension('ZAP', '.zap')`

The specs for the `_open` method are very clearly laid out in the chapter -- it must read image data and metadata from open binary file-like object `self.fp`, raise `SyntaxError` (or another exception) ASAP if it detects that the file's not actually in the right format, set at least `self.size` and `self.mode` attributes, and in order to allow *reading* the image, also `self.tile`, a list of *tile descriptors* again in the format specified in that chapter (including the file-offset, which you say you know, and a decoder -- if the raw or bit decoders, documented in the chapter, don't meet your needs, the chapter recommends studying the sources of some of the many supplied decoders, such as JPEG, PNG, etc).